# cron calling cv but not executing?

Tags: cron, cv, wp

WP4.9.6 / CiviCRM 5.1.2

Having some issues with cron jobs using cv. I have a cron running with cli.php but that requires a password. I'm about to implement 2FA which breaks that approach.

I've got cv installed (well technically my hosting provider installed it for me), and I can call it from ssh, but it doesn't seem to trigger the scheduled jobs (even when I replace admin with a valid WP / CiviCRM superuser account name)?

```
bash-3.2$ cv api job.execute --user=admin --cwd=/var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/public_html -vvv
[BootTrait] Start
[BootTrait] Attempting to set verbose error reporting 
[BootTrait] Call standard cv bootstrap
[Bootstrap] Options: {
  "dynamicSettingsFile": "phar:///var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/cv.phar/settings_location.php",
  "env": "CIVICRM_SETTINGS",
  "prefetch": true,
  "settingsFile": null,
  "search": true,
  "cmsType": null,
  "httpHost": "",
  "output": {} }

[Bootstrap] Find settings file
[Bootstrap] Load supplemental configuration for "/var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php"
[Bootstrap] Load settings file "/var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php"
[Bootstrap] Find CMS root for "/var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/public_html"
[Bootstrap] Found "wp" in "/var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/public_html"
[Bootstrap] Simulate web environment in CLI
[Bootstrap] Initialize class loader

[Bootstrap] Call core bootstrap 
[Bootstrap] Finished

[BootTrait] Call core bootstrap
[BootTrait] Call CMS bootstrap
```

My site is an upgrade from before 4.6 so my civicrm.settings.php is in ../plugins/civicrm which I've copied to ../uploads/civicrm just in case, but to no effect.

Everything seems to work, but nothing happens?

Comment: I do think you don't need the username in cv command for the cron. What would happen if you call cv from the civicrm directory?

Comment: The documentation includes user=admin so I figure it's needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this as I've managed to get wp-cli to work from ssh, just trying to get it to work from cron now....